# Listing or Archiving non binary files from a git repo

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm currently working on a Java project using JGit. I still didn't use JGit, but I'm assuming that its functionality would be quiet the same as what comes with normal git.

What I'm trying to do is to fetch all non binary files, and files below a certain size from a bare git repo branch, and archive them in a zip file. This task might be simple for a repo with a working directory, since I can simply use `git grep -Ic ''` to list all non binary files, and then pass those files to `git archive`, however this is not doable for bare repositories.

Would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JGit's `ArchiveCommand` to produce an archive. Its `setPaths()` method allows you to select only certain paths to be included.

In order to assemble the list of paths, you would want to analyze the tree of the commit to be archived. For example:

```java
TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk( repository );
treeWalk.setRecursive( true );
treeWalk.addTree( commit.getTree() );
while( treeWalk .next() ) {
  if( !isBinary( treeWalk ) {
    filesToArchive.add( treeWalk.getPathString() );
  }
}
treeWalk.close();
```

The example code walks the entire tree of the commit to be archived, obtains the contents of each file in the tree and calls the fictional `isBinary()` method to determine whether its content is text or binary. All non-binary files are added to the `filesToArchive` collection that can be passed to the `ArchiveCommand`.

For the `isBinary()` implementation you may succeed in using JGit's attribute support:

```java
Attributes attributes = new AttributesHandler( treeWalk ).getAttributes();
boolean binary = attributes.isSet( "binary" );
```

`AttributesHandler::getAttributes()` returns the *merged* attributes for the current path represented by the `treeWalk`.

Alternatively, you may use `RawText::isBinary()` to implement the `isBinary()` method like so:

```java
ObjectId blobId = treeWalk.getObjectId( 0 );
ObjectReader objectReader = repository.newObjectReader();
ObjectLoader objectLoader = objectReader.open( blobId );
byte[] bytes = objectLoader.getBytes();
objectReader.close();
boolean binary = RawText.isBinary( bytes );
```

`RawText::isBinary` uses the same heuristic as native Git to determine whether the given content is binary or text.

Comment: This is great. I just need to determine whether a file is binary or plain text. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Rüdiger again. Don't know how will I use `AttributesHandler.BINARY_RULE_KEY` since it's private, but I think that I'll be able to manage from here

Comment: Hello @RüdigerHerrmann. Unfortunately, the attributes for me are always empty. It seems that the JGit implementation tries to get it from the attributes file from within the git repo, and since this is not configured for the repositories I work with, I get nothing. Seems that I'll have to use the `ObjectReader` solution you suggested in the beginning. Just for completeness, `tree.next()` should be `treeWalk.next()` and in the current implementation, there's no need for the `ObjectId`, which was from the first solution. It would be great if the answer had both solutions for future reference.

Comment: OK, I ended up using `RawText.isBinary(byte[] bytes)` with your first solution, and it's working fine. Thanks a million for your help

Answer (score 0):

The command is named [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), and it's a lot nicer than having to bother with worktrees.

You can exclude unwanted files with the [`export-ignore` attribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_creating_an_archive), the repo-local `.git/info/attributes` (or in a bare repo like you have, just `info/attributes`) can be handy here.  Also, `git ls-files|git check-attr --stdin --all` is a handy starter kit for finding what's been tagged with what or for arbitrary commits (`git ls-tree -r --name-only your.ref.here|git check-attr -a --stdin`).

You can put arbitrary patterns into your attributes files, e.g.

```
*.jpg export-ignore
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I have several problems here. First of all, JGit does not completely support git attributes, and even if it does, as far as I understand, export-ignore specifies files and directories, not file types (basically binary files and extremely large files). I added the part about large files to the question now. Secondly, `git ls-files` doesn't work with bare repos (`git ls-tree` does though)

Comment: Just one other thing. `git check-attr` is really great, but as far as I understand, it will return the attributes as per the attributes file. Without any file from my side, git should be able to differentiate between text files and binary files. I just don't know how to get this info from git, let alone JGit

Comment: _Humans_ can have a hard time telling what's "binary" and what's not.  It's a characterization, and so it's a bit arbitrary.  Text in an unexpected encoding can look binary.  Git tries, or there's `find -type f | xargs -d\\n file | grep -v :.*text` to find everything that doesn't look like text to the "file" command as a starter kit.